# Remove duplicate records based on timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query to find duplicate records. I have table with following columns

```
Id, Deliveries, TankId, Timestamp.
```

I have inserted duplicate records, that is for same tankid, same deliveries with the +1 day offset timestamp.

Now I want to remove duplicate records which is with lesser timestamp.

e.g. I have duplicate deliveries added for same tankid on 24th and 25th july. I need to remove 24th record.

I tried the following query;

```
SELECT raw.TimeStamp,raw.[Delivery],raw.[TankId]
FROM  [dbo].[tObservationData] raw
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Delivery],[TankSystemId]
    FROM [dbo].[ObservationData] 
    GROUP BY [Delivery],[TankSystemId]
    HAVING COUNT([ObservationDataId]) > 1
    ) dup 
    ON raw.[Delivery] = dup.[Delivery] AND raw.[TankId] = dup.[TankId]
    AND  raw.TimeStamp >'2019-06-30 00:00:00.0000000' AND raw.[DeliveryL]>0
ORDER BY [TankSystemId],TimeStamp
```

But above gives other records too, how can I find and delete those duplicate records?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: just add in your subqery min(Timestamp) and add it in join

Comment: @Y.K. Could you please provide added change to my query as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think it will work

```
SELECT raw.TimeStamp,raw.[Delivery],raw.[TankId]
FROM  [dbo].[tObservationData] raw
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Delivery],[TankSystemId],min([TimeStamp]) as min_ts
    FROM [dbo].[ObservationData] 
    GROUP BY [Delivery],[TankSystemId]
    HAVING COUNT([ObservationDataId]) > 1
    ) dup 
    ON raw.[Delivery] = dup.[Delivery] AND raw.[TankId] = dup.[TankId] and raw.[TimeStamp] = dup.min_ts
    AND  raw.TimeStamp >'2019-06-30 00:00:00.0000000' AND raw.[DeliveryL]>0
ORDER BY [TankSystemId],TimeStamp
```

Comment: How to delete other record then?

Comment: I thought you want to delete only row with least timestamp

Comment: Yes..But this will list out what are the duplicate records, then I need to delete them? I have 1000s of records

Comment: don't quite understand the question, running this script you get a duplicate with the smallest date, then you can run `delete` statement

Comment: Sorry, Thanks YK

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for this?

```
SELECT od.*
FROM (SELECT od.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY od.TankId, od.Delivery ORDER BY od.TimeStamp DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[tObservationData] od
     ) od
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use partition by order by clause. You can partition by TankID and Delivery and order by Timestamp in desc order

```
Select * from (
Select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TankID,Delievry ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) AS rn
from [dbo].[ObservationData]
) 
where rn = 1
```

In the above code records with rn=1 will have the latest timestamp. So you can only select those and ignore others. Also you can use the same to remove/delete the records from you table.

```
WITH TempObservationdata (TankID,Delivery,Timestamp)
AS
(
SELECT TankID,Delivery,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by TankID, Delivery ORDER BY Timsetamp desc) 
AS Timestamp
FROM dbo.ObservationData
)
--Now Delete Duplicate Rows
DELETE FROM TempObservationdata 
WHERE Timestamp > 1
```